# Select daily files in r

Tags: r, file, select

I have some files that it named day and time such as

```
2015080103100400dBZ.txt    2015090100100600dBZ.txt
2015090101000500dBZ.txt    2015090101500400dBZ.txt
2015090102400400dBZ.txt    2015090102500400dBZ.txt
2015090103300400dBZ.txt    2015090104000600dBZ.txt
2015090104200400dBZ.txt    2015090104300400dBZ.txt
2015090106000600dBZ.txt    2015090107100500dBZ.txt
2015090107500500dBZ.txt    2015090108100500dBZ.txt
2015090108300500dBZ.txt    2015090109200500dBZ.txt
2015090109300500dBZ.txt    2015090111000700dBZ.txt
2015090111200500dBZ.txt    2015090111300500dBZ.txt
2015090203400500dBZ.txt    2015090204300500dBZ.txt
2015090204500500dBZ.txt    2015090205000700dBZ.txt
2015090205200500dBZ.txt    2015090205500500dBZ.txt
2015090206300500dBZ.txt    2015090207300300dBZ.txt
2015090208500300dBZ.txt    2015090209200300dBZ.txt
2015090210400300dBZ.txt    2015090210500300dBZ.txt
2015090211400300dBZ.txt    2015090211500300dBZ.txt
2015090212400400dBZ.txt    2015090213100400dBZ.txt
2015090213500400dBZ.txt    2015090214200400dBZ.txt
2015090214300400dBZ.txt    2015090215000600dBZ.txt
2015090216200400dBZ.txt    2015090217000600dBZ.txt
2015090217100400dBZ.txt    2015090218100400dBZ.txt
2015090218400400dBZ.txt    2015090219000600dBZ.txt
2015090219100500dBZ.txt    2015090219200500dBZ.txt
2015090219300500dBZ.txt    2015090219500500dBZ.txt
2015090220400500dBZ.txt    2015090221000700dBZ.txt
2015090221400500dBZ.txt    2015090222200500dBZ.txt
2015090222400500dBZ.txt    2015090223100500dBZ.txt
2015090300000700dBZ.txt    2015090300100500dBZ.txt
2015090300500600dBZ.txt    2015090301000400dBZ.txt
2015090301100300dBZ.txt    2015090301200300dBZ.txt
2015090302400300dBZ.txt    2015090303000500dBZ.txt
2015090303200300dBZ.txt    2015090303300300dBZ.txt
2015090303500300dBZ.txt    2015090304000500dBZ.txt
2015090307400400dBZ.txt    2015090308000500dBZ.txt
...
```

It is not same length of files in a day, and i want select it in daily to process. I want to process

```
2015080103100400dBZ.txt                             in day 20150801
2015090100100600dBZ.txt to 2015090111300500dBZ.txt  in day 20150901
2015090203400500dBZ.txt to 2015090223100500dBZ.txt  in day 20150902
etc
```

How to select it?
From the result, i want to open each file for looping

Comment: Do you mean you want to select all files from one day? So e.g. all files from 2015/09/01? And what then, read them in?

Comment: You need to be clear about what you need and to have looked up alternative solutions before asking. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit vague, but I'll take a stab: you want to split these file names up by day, so that all filenames from a particular day are somehow grouped together for your processing.

Ideally, you would do something like:

```
filenames <- list.files(somedir, full.names = TRUE)
```

but for now I'll use your static data as an example.

```
filenames <- strsplit('2015080103100400dBZ.txt
2015090100100600dBZ.txt
2015090101000500dBZ.txt
2015090101500400dBZ.txt
2015090102400400dBZ.txt
2015090102500400dBZ.txt
2015090103300400dBZ.txt
2015090104000600dBZ.txt
2015090104200400dBZ.txt
2015090104300400dBZ.txt
2015090106000600dBZ.txt
2015090107100500dBZ.txt
2015090107500500dBZ.txt
2015090108100500dBZ.txt
2015090108300500dBZ.txt
2015090109200500dBZ.txt
2015090109300500dBZ.txt
2015090111000700dBZ.txt
2015090111200500dBZ.txt
2015090111300500dBZ.txt', '[\r\n]')[[1]]

head(filenames)
# [1] "2015080103100400dBZ.txt" "2015090100100600dBZ.txt"
# [3] "2015090101000500dBZ.txt" "2015090101500400dBZ.txt"
# [5] "2015090102400400dBZ.txt" "2015090102500400dBZ.txt"
```

From here, just split them up by the first 8 characters of the filename:

```
grouped <- split(filenames, substr(basename(filenames), 1, 8))
grouped
# $`20150801`
# [1] "2015080103100400dBZ.txt"
# $`20150901`
#  [1] "2015090100100600dBZ.txt" "2015090101000500dBZ.txt"
#  [3] "2015090101500400dBZ.txt" "2015090102400400dBZ.txt"
#  [5] "2015090102500400dBZ.txt" "2015090103300400dBZ.txt"
#  [7] "2015090104000600dBZ.txt" "2015090104200400dBZ.txt"
#  [9] "2015090104300400dBZ.txt" "2015090106000600dBZ.txt"
# [11] "2015090107100500dBZ.txt" "2015090107500500dBZ.txt"
# [13] "2015090108100500dBZ.txt" "2015090108300500dBZ.txt"
# [15] "2015090109200500dBZ.txt" "2015090109300500dBZ.txt"
# [17] "2015090111000700dBZ.txt" "2015090111200500dBZ.txt"
# [19] "2015090111300500dBZ.txt"
```

Notes:

- the names within the list are numeric, so you'll need do use either of the following:

  ```
  grouped$`20150801`
  grouped[["20150801"]]
  ```
- this produces a list of filenames, I'm assuming that you have another mechanism somewhere that, given a vector of filenames, will smartly import them
- I used `basename` in the call to `substr` in the event your call to `list.files` includes `full.names=TRUE` and there is a directory component to the path, such as `"path/to/2015090111200500dBZ.txt"`; if they are always in the same directory (or the directory is imposed in other code), then you don't need `basename`

**EDIT**

The premise of having a variable number of filenames in a list like this is that operating on the list of filenames as a whole may help you be more efficient with your entire process. For instance,

```
alldata <- lapply(grouped[["20150901"]], read.table)
```

will give you a list, where `alldata[[1]]` is all data from the first file, `alldata[[2]]` from the second, etc. Now with that, I'm assuming there is a function or sequence of commands you execute on each file's data. If that's the case, then you can do something like

```
processeddata <- lapply(alldata, function(dat) {
    # do something with a single data.frame, from one file
    dat$newcolumn <- paste(dat$column2, "hey")
    dat
})
```

One possible step would be to combine all of these individual files into one big one, such as

```
combineddata <- do.call(rbind, c(processeddata, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

and now you have a single dataframe for all files included in day "20150901".

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i have a problem to open the files with command read.table(grouped$'20150901'[1])...why i is not work?

Comment: Are you using single-ticks or back-ticks in that command? I warned against this in the answer, perhaps use `read.table(grouped[["20150901"]][1])`. Better yet, how about `alldata <- lapply(grouped[["20150901"]], read.table)`, and you have all data within a list.

Comment: See my edits towards possibly streamlining your processing of variable numbers of files. A `for` loop can approximate this, but I find doing things in lists/vectors like this can take you from manually processing 20 files to doing it once and repeating with as many at a time as you can imagine.

Comment: i find it. i use 

    pp<-unlist(grouped$'20150801')
    data <- read.table(pp[1],sep=",")

so it can be looped for all grouped

    n <- length(grouped)
    for (i in 1:n){
     data <- read.table(pp[1],sep=",")
            ..........
    }

Comment: If this answers your question, please edit your question and add some more info that justifies re-opening it. After that, I think you'll be able to "accept" this answer.